# Parse ruby int to PHP date

Tags: php, ruby, time

Is there a way to parse an integer generated from ruby's Time class (with gmt) to a date in PHP?

Here's an example:

```
int : 1463616000000
```

When I tried to parse it with this code:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', 1463616000000);
```

The output is:

> 48350-02-22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby's Time class returns a timestamp in miliseconds rather than seconds. Just divide by 1,000 for PHP:

```
$ts = 1463616000000;
$ts /= 1000;
echo date('Y-m-d', $ts); // 2016-05-19
```